# problemas con textarea y php

Tags: php, mysql, bootstrap

Tengo 2 `textarea` y el usuario pone varios enteros y hace la búsqueda bien, el problema es cuando el coloca un `enter` de mas al final el programa falla, alguna idea?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta aquí todo bien pero después vienen los posibles fallos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí es como proceso la información que recibo en el `textarea`.

```
 $supertoken_id = $_POST['supertoken_id'];
 $num_bug = $_POST['num_bug'];


 if($num_bug!="")
 {
           $onlyconsonants = str_replace("\n", ',',$num_bug);
                   $arregloTokens = explode(",",$onlyconsonants);
                   $longitud=count($arregloTokens);
                   $vowels = array();
                   for ($i=0; $i <$longitud ; $i++) 
                   { 
                     $vowels[$i]=trim($arregloTokens[$i]);
                   }
                   $stringParaIn = implode(",",$vowels);



  //echo "numero de bucc";
    $sql = "select * FROM _tablacompleta WHERE num_bug IN (".$stringParaIn.")";

 $sql2 = "select * FROM _noarribados WHERE num_bug IN (".$stringParaIn.")";

}

if($supertoken_id!="")
{


          $onlyconsonants = str_replace("\n", ',',$supertoken_id);
         $arregloTokens = explode(",",$onlyconsonants);
         $longitud=count($arregloTokens);
         $vowels = array();
         for ($i=0; $i <$longitud ; $i++) 
         { 
           $vowels[$i]=trim($arregloTokens[$i]);
         }
         $stringParaIn = implode(",",$vowels);


            //echo "numero de token";
             $sql = "select * FROM _tablacompleta WHERE supertoken_id IN (".$stringParaIn.")";

           $sql2 = "select * FROM _noarribados WHERE supertoken_id IN (".$stringParaIn.")";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Porque al hacer `explode()` y tiene un línea vacía te devuelve un string vacío `""` entonces al hacer después la query tira error. Podrías cambiar ese `explode()` por un [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split) y decirle que te devuelva todo menos los que están vacíos. Por ejemplo:

```
<?php
  ...
  $onlyconsonants = str_replace("\n", ',',$num_bug);
  $arregloTokens = preg_split("@,@", $onlyconsonants, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  ...
```